# Parsing HTML to get all Option tags with PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm parsing and HTML page that contains a:

```
<select>
    <option value="somevalue">Somedata</option>
</select>
```

And I need to get both somevalue and somedata out of there.

What's the easiest way to go about this?
It should be noted that somevalue and Somedata is always different (So to speak)

It is formed like:

```
 <select name="attrib1" class="Input">
    <option value="0">&nbsp;</option>
    <option value="140">140</option>
    <option value="141">150</option>
    <option value="142">160</option>
  </select>
```

Please note, the name is **ALWAYS** attrib1!

Comment: The answer will depend on if this HTML is valid or not. SimpleXML is very easy to use, but it won't be of much use if you try to pass it a non-conforming HTML document.

Comment: I've edited the original post to reflect how it looks. Will SimpleXML be usable here? If so, how?

Comment: Are you able to show the full document? Or is that it?

Comment: The title of this question is completely useless.

Comment: @pt2ph8 fixed. I assume the change was accidental.

Comment: @phihag Ah sorry, didn't notice it was correct before.

Comment: @Onteria: no, sorry :/ that is unfortunately all I can show.

Comment: @Eax well, I used a more forgiving method just in case. The answer is down below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, since I can't see the full HTML, I'm not really sure if it's well formed, so I'll attempt to do this using more forgiving DOM functions.  First off, I'm going to use this minimal html file as a sample:

**test.html**

```
<html>
<body>
 <select name="attrib1" class="Input">
    <option value="0">&nbsp;</option>
    <option value="140">140</option>
    <option value="141">150</option>
    <option value="142">160</option>
  </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Now then, the first thing we need to do is create a DOM parser. We'll do this like so:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("test.html");
```

> Okay, next we'll need to look at the
>   requirements:
>
> I'm parsing and HTML page that
>   contains a:
>
> ```
> <select>
>   <option value="somevalue">Somedata</option>
> </select>
> ```
>
> And I need to get both somevalue and
>   somedata out of there.

You also mention:

> Please note, the name is ALWAYS attrib1!

Based on these requirements, I'm going to select all option tags that are a child of selects with the name "attrib1". To do so, I'm going to use something called XPath. This is a very flexible way to select dom elements based on specific conditions. Let's slowly build this out:

```
*/ 
select all elements

*/select 
select all elements that are select elements

*/select[@name='attrib1'] 
select all elements that are select elements with the name of attrib1

*/select[@name='attrib1']/option select all 
select all option elements under all select elements with the name of attrib1
```

Now then, we need to do this lookup, so we use the XPath functions:

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$options = $xpath->query("*/select[@name='attrib1']/option");
foreach ($options as $option) {
}
```

Now we need the value attribute, and the text inside. We'll first get the value attribute:

```
$optionValue = $option->getAttribute('value');
```

Then we get what's inside the option tag:

```
$optionContent = $option->nodeValue;
```

And once we put this all together:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("test.html");

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$options = $xpath->query("*/select[@name='attrib1']/option");
foreach ($options as $option) {
  $optionValue = $option->getAttribute('value');
  $optionContent = $option->nodeValue;
  echo "$optionValue and $optionContent\n";
}
```

We'll get the following output:

```
0 and  
140 and 140
141 and 150
142 and 160
```

And there you have it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works perfectly :) I wish I could upvote you, but alas, I don't have enough reputation :(

Nonetheless, thank you very much!

Comment: @Eax Just enter '↑ ↑ ↓ ↓ ← → ← → B A start' at the main screen for unlimited reputation

Comment: Well, I know that the Konami code fixes EVERYTHING, but it seriously works? :P (You might be pulling my leg here.. But the Devs of SO might be that awesome..) Also, there's no start button on my keyboard xD

Answer (score 2):

Use http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Please do not try to use regex

HTML is not a regular language. Trying to parse it as such, will at first glance seem to work, however it will definitively bite you in the ass later.

Comment: Yeah, maybe some explanation why do you ask people not to use regular expressions? ;)

Comment: An HTML document represents structure. Regex is not able to comprehend this structure. Say for example you want only `<option>` that are children of a specific div? A regex version would have no understanding of where each option element lies in respect to higher level elements. It's just trying to match a pattern against text. That's why a lot of people are recommending not to parse HTML with a regex.

Comment: @George: At some point regex will bite you in the ass. Regex are not suitable to parse HTML. A HTML parser is.

Comment: In general, ofcourse an HTML parser it the right thing to choose, but in the specific situation I don't see how the regex might have some problem.

Comment: Maybe it would work right now. But as I have stated it WILL bite you in the ass later. Trust me on that one. And that's from my personal experience

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question:

The easiest way is to use [regular expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) with [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) function.

You have to create some regular expression matching all option tags and extracting both values you need.

Comment: I have to disagree here. A DOM parser would more accurately obtain the necessary values (assuming it's well-formed, which if it's not a regex solution will be even more madness) without the complicated edge cases that a regular expression would involve.