# Iterating over DOMNodes using Xpath

Tags: php, foreach, domxpath

I was trying to extract the contents of the options tags from some html, using the approach in this 8-year old thread:
[Parsing HTML to get all Option tags with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079041/parsing-html-to-get-all-option-tags-with-php)
The only difference is that I had the html as a string, rather than in a file, so with appropriate modification my test program is:

```
$html = "<select name='test'><option value='1'>opt1</option><option value='2'>opt1</option><option   value='3'>opt1</option></select>"; 
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadXML($html);
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);        # parse out each option

    // parse the options
    $options = $xpath->query("*/select[1]/option");
    var_dump ($options);

    foreach ($options as $option) {
        $optionContent = $option->textContent;
        echo ($optionContent);
    }
```

The query appears to work - the output from the var_dump is:

```
object(DOMNodeList)[3]
```

However, I don't get any option content, and it seems that it is not executing any of the "foreach" loops. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I guess you have wrong query, try your code with `$xpath->query("/select[1]/option")`

Comment: Thank you Andrii. I can't mark your comment as the answer, but it was clearly right. I will have to try to understand why the 8-year old recipe didn't work, and this did, so there is some learning of xpath queries needed on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way and see if it works:

```
$options = $xpath->query("/select//option");
    foreach ($options as $option) {

        echo($option->textContent);

    }
```